# Passing a function with void pointer as argument gives warning

Tags: c, parameter-passing, warnings

I implemented a queue and want a function that prints its elements, regardless of the type. So I made a function printQueue as follows:

```
void printQueue(queue_t *queue, void (*f)(void *)) {
  node_t *node = (*queue).front;
  while(node != NULL) {
    (*f)(node->item);
    puts("");
    node = (*node).next;
  }
}
```

The idea is that it will receive the queue, and a function to print an element from the queue (the queue was implemented to be able to hold any kind of element). So this function would iterate the queue and call that function to print each of it's elements.

Then I made a function to print arrays of ints which contain their own size in it's first element as follows:

```
void printSpecialIntArray(int *array) {
  int i;
  for(i=0; i<array[0]; i++) {
    printf("%d ", array[i]);
  }
}
```

However if I initialize a queue say `Q` with that kind of arrays and call `printQueue(Q, printSpecialIntArray)` it seems to work as intended but I get a warning:

```
warning: passing argument 2 of ‘printQueue’ from incompatible pointer type [-Wincompatible-pointer-types]
   printQueue(Q, printSpecialIntArray);
                   ^~~~~~~~~~~~
In file included from main.c:3:0:
queue.c:32:6: note: expected ‘void (*)(void *)’ but argument is of type ‘void (*)(int *)’
 void printQueue(queue_t *queue, void (*f)(void *)) {
```

Why does this warning happen and how can it be fixed? Is there a cleaner way to do this?

Also if you're wondering, I'm using an array which has it's own size as an element because I'm implementing a process simulator, and those "Special int arrays" are actually supposed to represent a process. If you know a cleaner way to do that I would also appreciate if you include in your answer/comment.

Comment: If `printQueue` should take a a `void (*f)(int*)`, why did you define it to take a `void (*f)(void *)` instead?

Comment: The error message is clear.

Comment: @Blaze not necessarily. In this case if I'm using a queue of `int*`, it should accept it. But if I were to for example use a queue of `char *` and make a function to print it, I want that to be possible too. I used `void *` because I thought that would let me use a pointer to any type of data.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The error message is very straight forward. The function `void printQueue(queue_t *queue, void (*f)(void *))` expects `f` to be a pointer to a function returning `void` and taking exactly one argument and its type should be `void*`. The function `printSpecialIntArray` does not fulfill this, since it's argument is `int*`.

One solution is to change `f` so that it takes `int*` as argument instead of `void*`. Another solution is to rewrite `printSpecialIntArray`:

```
void printSpecialIntArray(void *a) {
  int *array = (int*) a;
  int i;
  for(i=0; i<array[0]; i++) {
    printf("%d ", array[i]);
  }
}
```

**Note:**

Even though a void pointer can be safely promoted to an int pointer, the function `f` still needs to be a function that takes a void pointer as argument. It's not the argument that's the problem, it's the function declaration itself.

Answer (score 3):

Your function signature does not match.
You need to provide the expected signature and cast the pointer according to your needs:

```
void printSpecialIntArray(void *arr) {
  int array = (int *)arr;
  int i;
  for(i=0; i<array[0]; i++) {
    printf("%d ", array[i]);
  }
}
```